# XML.Save file writing mystery

Tags: c#, xml

What I'm trying to do here is see whether the element exists in the xml document, if it does exist then i want to modify the inner text of it. if it doesnt exist i would like to create it and also create the appropriate inner text for it. However, when it an element does exist and i try to change it's inner text to something shorter than it was the whole xml files writing seems to shift.

My code:

```
                XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmldoc.Load(path);
                XmlNodeList felement = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName(Element);
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
                if (felement.Count == 0)
                {
                    XmlElement elmRoot = xmldoc.DocumentElement;
                    XmlElement xmlele = xmldoc.CreateElement(Element);
                    xmlele.AppendChild(xmldoc.CreateTextNode(data));
                    elmRoot.AppendChild(xmlele);
                    xmldoc.Save(fs);
                }
                else
                {
                    felement[0].InnerText = data;
                    xmldoc.Save(fs);
                }
                fs.Close();
```

XML File before modifying with a shorter inner text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyXMLFile>
  <Source>C:\Users\Dacto\Desktop\</Source>
  <Destination>C:\Program Files\Adobe</Destination>
</MyXMLFile>
```

After shorter inner text:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyXMLFile>
  <Source>C:\Users\Dacto\Desktop\Napster</Source>
  <Destination>C:\Users</Destination>
</MyXMLFile>/MyXMLFile>
```

See the "extra" /MyXMLFile>  what's going on??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the output isn't valid XML then it's unlikely that XmlDocument.Save produced the entire content of the file.  Given this, I'd suspect that when creating the FileStream you should supply a different parameter rather than FileMode.Open - FileMode.Create will ensure that the file is truncated before being written to - currently it's being overwritten, leaving the old content in place if the new file isn't large enough to cover it.

Comment: That is what appears to be happening, I changed it to FileMode.Truncate - and it works :)

Comment: Glad to hear.  If there's a chance the file wont exist to start with, FileMode.Create is the best bet, as it will either create the file, or truncate it, depending on whether it already exists.

Comment: In some code prior to that i check whether the path actually exists, if not it will create it.

Comment: Another option is to use `XmlDocument.Save(String filename)` and dispense with the FileStream if you've not a particular need for that little extra complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with they way that you are writing out the file, not with the xml. If you try something like,

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("AAAAA");
fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
```

You should see:

```
AAAAA version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyXMLFile>
  <Source>C:\Users\Dacto\Desktop\</Source>
  <Destination>C:\Program Files\Adobe</Destination>
</MyXMLFile>
```

Instead of FileMode.Open, you want FileMode.Create, so that the file gets truncated before you write to it if it exists already.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that you have to save the XmlDocument is through the use of an XmlWriter instead of a FileStream.

```
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmldoc.Load(path);
    XmlNodeList felement = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName(Element);

    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;

    using (XmlWriter wr = XmlWriter.Create(path), settings))
    {
        if (felement.Count == 0)
        {
            XmlElement elmRoot = xmldoc.DocumentElement;
            XmlElement xmlele = xmldoc.CreateElement(Element);
            xmlele.AppendChild(xmldoc.CreateTextNode(data));
            elmRoot.AppendChild(xmlele);
            xmldoc.Save(wr);
        }
        else
        {
            felement[0].InnerText = data;
            xmldoc.Save(wr);
        }
    }
```

Also, if you continue with your original FileStream method, then I would recommend wrapping it in a using statement like I have done above with the XmlWriter and if you do, then you can get rid of the fs.Close() statement.